# How to integrate Apple maps with iphone applications

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What is the difference in integrating Google maps and apple map. Whether MKMapView in ios6 loads Google or apple map. How to integrate apple maps with iphone apples.

Comment: it depends on iOS of device, if less than 6, then Google Maps, if 6 or greater than Apple Maps

Answer (score 2):

Since iOS 6 Apple has removed Google Maps, when your app uses `MKMapView` it will be using Apple maps in iOS 6 and higher and Google map in iOS 5 and lower.